# Interpolation between $H^1$ and $H^1\cap L^1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, interpolation

Suppose that $T:H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a linear bounded operator, with operator norm $M_2$. In particular, given $1\leq p\leq2$, there exist optimal constants $M_p\leq M_2$ such that
$$|Tf|\leq M_p(\Vert f\Vert_{H^1}+\Vert f\Vert_{L^p})$$
for every $f\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)\cap L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Suppose $M_1<M_2$. How can i bound $M_p$ in terms of $M_1$ and $M_2$?

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Can you please be more explicit about what $H^1$ denotes: is it the real Hardy space $H^1$ or the Sobolev space $H^1$ ?

Comment: Is the Sobolev space